# Set Value of an Input Inside a Form with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to set an input's value with useState but it doesn't work the way I want it.

So I have a weekly schedule created with Formik for an appointment system. I have radio buttons for free appointments. And when selected I get the time data for the appointment. But I don't get the day. So I tried to add another input to get day data. I set the value of input to a state. And when a radio button selected it sets the day. But onSubmit I get the initial value, not the newly set value. And the funny thing is when I try to write something in my input, it returns my desired value + last key I pressed. But if I don't do anything, it just returns initial value.

Initial values of my form:

```
const [day, setDay] = useState("Gün");

<Formik
    onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
    initialValues={{
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
    date: "",
    day: day,
    }}
>
```

My radio button where I set my state:

```
<Field
    type="radio"
    name="date"
    value={x.monPm3Time}
    onClick={() => {
        setDay("Pazartesi");
    }}
/>
```

And my input where its value set to state:

```
<Field
    id="day"
    name="day"
    value = {day}
/>
```

My handleSubmit function (I'm just loggin them for now to see if it works):

```
const handleFormSubmit = async (values) => {
        console.log(values);
        // fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/appointment", {
        //  method: "POST",
        //  body: values,
        //  headers: {
        //      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        //  },
        // })
        //  .then((res) => {
        //      console.log(res.status);
        //  })
        //  .catch((err) => {
        //      console.log(err);
        //  });
}
```

Comment: I think adding the handleSubmit code will help us help you

Comment: I'm just logging values from Formik so I didn't bother sharing it but let me share it.

Answer (score 1):

So I've tried to replicate (as best as I could) your issue in a code editor, and I'm able to change the text in the input when the radio button is clicked. You can find my implementation here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b5rvzg?file=src%2FApp.js

I also believe that you're not passing anything to your handleFormSubmit function, so you're not going to see anything. I could be wrong because I can't fully see how your code is set up

Comment: I also am able change the text in the input but when submitted, it still submits the initial value. And I'm passing values from Formik. So my submit function should work fine. The thing is when I try to write something inside day input after radio button get clicked and submit after that, it returns my desired value + last key I pressed. So for some reason it only assigns the desired value after some change occured inside input.